# How can I establish a decreasing relationship between variables?

Tags: netlogo

I am a teacher of Primary Education and Early Childhood Education and I am trying to generate a simulator through NetLogo on how fertilization and pesticides are decimating the butterfly population. However, despite having read the manual, I am not managing to program the code to make it work.

My problem is that **although I set the turtles I can't establish the following relationship between the variables/buttons**:

**If butterflies randomly touch a plant (which is fertilized with pesticide) its pollinating capacity is reduced by a certain percentage (depends on the amount of pesticide)**

**My problem is that I can't get the pollination capacity of the butterfly to be set to 100% initially and that the greater the amount of pesticide, the lower its pollination capacity is when touching a flower. Currently, although the amount of pesticide is the highest, there are peaks where its pollination capacity increases instead of being reduced.**

```
breed [butterflies butterfly]
breed [flowers flower]

globals
[
  butterfliesless-neighborhoods       ;; how many patches have no butterflies in any neighboring patches?
  pollinating-capacity            ;; measures how well-bivouaced the butterflies are
]
patches-own
[
  butterflies-nearby                  ;; how many butterflies in neighboring patches?
]
flowers-own
[
  carried-butterflies         ;; the butterflies I'm carrying (or nobody if I'm not carrying in)
  found-bivouac?           ;; becomes true when I find a bivouac to drop it in
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape butterflies "butterflies"
  set-default-shape flowers "flower"
  ask patches
    [ set pcolor green + (random-float 0.8) - 0.4]   ;; varying the green just makes it look nicer
  create-butterflies num-butterflies
    [ set color white
      set size 1.5  ;; easier to see
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
  create-flowers num-flowers
    [ set color brown
      set size 1.5  ;; easier to see
      set carried-butterflies nobody
      set found-bivouac? false
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
  reset-ticks
end

to update-butterflies-counts
  ask patches
    [ set butterflies-nearby (sum [count butterflies-here] of neighbors) ]
  set butterfliesless-neighborhoods (count patches with [butterflies-nearby = 0])
end

to calculate-pollinating-capacity
  set pollinating-capacity (butterfliesless-neighborhoods / (count patches with [not any? butterflies-here])) * 100
end

to go
  ask flowers
  [ ifelse carried-butterflies = nobody
      [ search-for-butterflies ]     ;; find a butterflies and pick it up
    [ ifelse found-bivouac?
        [ find-empty-spot ]  ;; find an empty spot to drop the butterflies
      [ find-new-bivouac ] ]  ;; find a bivouac to drop the butterflies in
    wiggle
    fd 1
    if carried-butterflies != nobody
    ;; bring my butterflies to where I just moved to
    [ ask carried-butterflies [ move-to myself ] ] ]
  ask butterflies with [not hidden?]
  [ wiggle
    fd pesticide-amount ]
  tick
end

to wiggle        ;; turtle procedure
  rt random 50 - random 50
end

to search-for-butterflies ;; flowers procedure
  set carried-butterflies one-of butterflies-here with [not hidden?]
  if (carried-butterflies != nobody)
    [ ask carried-butterflies
        [ hide-turtle ]  ;; make the butterflies invisible to other flowers
      set color blue     ;; turn flower blue while carrying butterflies
      fd 1 ]
end

to find-new-bivouac ;; flowers procedure
  if any? butterflies-here with [not hidden?]
    [ set found-bivouac? true ]
end

to find-empty-spot ;; flowers procedure
  if all? butterflies-here [hidden?]
    [ ask carried-butterflies
        [ show-turtle ]       ;; make the butterflies visible again
      set color brown         ;; set my own color back to brown
      set carried-butterflies nobody
      set found-bivouac? false
      rt random 360
      fd 20 ]
end
```

[Defined Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmwBL.png)

Comment: Hi Carmen, that is absolutely doable but this type of questions in Stackoverflow should describe what you have in your code and how it is giving you problems. Also, this will give others the necessary information to give you a meaningful and workable answer instead of an extremely vague one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the annotation. I just edited the question to make it more specific and include the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is a nice start with sliders, buttons and plots. In the code tab consider making two breeds of turtles: butterflies and plants.

```
breed [butterflies butterfly]
butterflies-own [pollinatingCapacity]

breed [plants plant]
plants-own [pesticideAmount]
```

And then think about how you might decrease pollinatingCapacity of a butterfly when it is on the same patch as a plant. A butterfly can see if any plants are on the same patch using `plants-here`

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. I have managed to have the variables and buttons involved. However, I still have not managed to make the relationship between them detrimental. My problem is that I can't get the pollination capacity of the butterfly to be set to 100% initially and that the greater the amount of pesticide, the lower its pollination capacity is when touching a flower. Currently, although the amount of pesticide is the highest, there are peaks where its pollination capacity increases instead of being reduced. Thanks for your time and response!